# skip the /data & / partition from output for fstab

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the below output, i want to get rid of /data & / as well in the output.

```
cat /etc/fstab  | egrep -v '^#' | awk '{print $2}'| grep -i "^/" | egrep -v '/etc/fstab|proc|sys|shm|pts|/apps|/boot|home|/opt|/var|/var|/crash|/tmp|"' > /tmp/mounts.txt
```

Output:

```
/
/data
/data/logs/mount1
/data/logs/mount2
```

I just need /data/logs/mount1 & /data/logs/mount2 to be displayed. Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
KG

Comment: Add  " | grep /data/"  that will not match / and /data ?

Comment: Thanks Namokarm.. it worked.

Comment: I've added my comment also as an answer, please mark it if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add " | grep /data/" that will not match / and /data.

For your example that is:

```
cat /etc/fstab  | egrep -v '^#' | awk '{print $2}'| grep -i "^/" | egrep -v '/etc/fstab|proc|sys|shm|pts|/apps|/boot|home|/opt|/var|/var|/crash|/tmp|"' | grep /data/ > /tmp/mounts.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

awk can do all that your pipeline does:

```
awk '
    # skip comments and empty lines
    $1 ~ /^#/ || NF == 0 {next}
    # skip mountpoints not beginning with a slash
    $2 ~/^[^/]/ {next}
    # skip / and /data
    $2 == "/" || $2 == "/data" {next}
    {print $2}
' /etc/fstab
```

or, if you're a fan of linenoise:

```
awk 'NF&&$1!~/^#/&&$2!~/^[^/]/&&$2!="/"&&$2!="/data" {print $2}' /etc/fstab
```